# Is it possible to serve up static images that are processed (and cached) by ImageResizing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I am testing out parts of the [ImageResizing](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache) library, specifically resizing, diskcache and watermarking.

I believe I have everything installed correctly and URL links like:

```
<img src="/images/tests/mytest.png?w=300&watermark=style1" />
```

render well in the browser, and also cache to disk with a random/hashed filename.  However, I can't figure out how to serve up static images with the watermark on them.  I was hoping that the diskcache would be able to serve up the cached image based on its filename alone, but looking at it, I imagine it needs the querystring along with it (indeed it renders fine served statically with the querystring).

my `<resizer>` section of web.config reads:

```
<resizer>
    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
    <plugins>
      <add name="DiskCache" />
      <add name="AdvancedFilters" />
      <add name="Watermark" />
      <add name="SimpleFilters" />
    </plugins>
    <diskCache dir="~/imagecache" />
    <watermarks>
      <otherimages path="~/site/watermarks" />
      <image name="style" path="~/site/watermarks/wmtest.png" imageQuery="filter=alpha(0.65)" Top="175" Left="32" />
    </watermarks>
  </resizer>
```

On the surface, I like the way [ImageDraw](http://www.neodynamic.com/products/image-draw/aspnet/) (another very capable library) handles caching as you are able to name the cachefile and the cached file gets served up even when requested in a static fashion.  The downside is that ImageDraw can be much heavier to program for in the codebehind.

My primary goal is to have certain images watermarked with copyright info which can't be circumvented by modifying a querystring.  The secondary goals are to provide fast efficient resizing and caching especially on thumbnails.  ImageResizing seems very well suited for my secondary goals, but it looks like caching only works with the querystring option (documented), unless I've missed another way ... hence my main question.

Also, if it's not clear, I am testing both libraries (**ImageResizing** and **ImageDraw**) to see which one weighs in better for our needs.  Right now I'm working locally on Cassini, but the deployment will be to an IIS7 server with the app running under ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Caching works for any HTTP request handled by the ImageResizer HttpModule, and the results are served as static files.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist My question, perhaps as silly as it seems, stands and you have answered it.  My understanding of httphandlers and modules is incomplete and I believe I am looking at things from the wrong angle.  I see the caching taking place when I use the querystrings, but without the strings no caching takes place, which of course, now makes perfect sense.  Why cache an unprocessed image?  My question stemmed from a misunderstanding and I should have narrowed in on my design requirement first (which I will expand upon below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, that is how it works. Images are cached to static files by the DiskCache plugin, and the urls are rewritten after that point.

Comment: The html portion of my design requirement is working fine, however, it is also requested that hotlinked files get processing as well (watermark).  There are unauthorized uses of the site's images out there and they should at least be gently watermarked.  Do I need to create my own handler or can I somehow automatically pass off handling to ImageResizer if the images sit in certain directories?  If that's possible it would likely complete my solution.  I'm really enjoying testing your software.  Thanks for makin' it.

Comment: You can use the Config.Current.Rewrite event to dynamically watermark hotlinked images (or any other criteria available in the http context). They'll be cached separately at the ImageResizer level, although you would have to use a redirect if you were using a CDN.

Comment: Do you mean I should refer to [How to require a watermark...](http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/watermark-by-folder-or-size) and handle this stuff in Application_Start?

Comment: Using those instructions, that seems to solve the issue I was having with Cassini not serving static image requests to the browser.